# Add span inside views pager

Tags: 7, views, theming

I need to add a single span inside of the list items of a views pager. This needs to be there even when the list item doesnt contain a link (when you are on the current pager's page).

I cant see any tpl files for doing this (my preferred method as im more of a themer.)

Ive looked for a theme override and ive found the following. The problem is that I cant figure where I would add the span.

```
function theme_views_mini_pager($vars) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

  $tags = $vars['tags'];
  $element = $vars['element'];
  $parameters = $vars['parameters'];

  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // max is the maximum page number
  $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
  // End of marker calculations.

  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {

    $li_previous = theme('pager_previous',
      array(
        'text' => (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('‹‹')),
        'element' => $element,
        'interval' => 1,
        'parameters' => $parameters,
      )
    );
    if (empty($li_previous)) {
      $li_previous = "&nbsp;";
    }

    $li_next = theme('pager_next',
      array(
        'text' => (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('››')),
        'element' => $element,
        'interval' => 1,
        'parameters' => $parameters,
      )
    );

    if (empty($li_next)) {
      $li_next = "&nbsp;";
    }

    $items[] = array(
      'class' => array('pager-previous'),
      'data' => $li_previous,
    );

    $items[] = array(
      'class' => array('pager-current'),
      'data' => t('@current of @max', array('@current' => $pager_current, '@max' => $pager_max)),
    );

    $items[] = array(
      'class' => array('pager-next'),
      'data' => $li_next,
    );
    return theme('item_list',
      array(
        'items' => $items,
        'title' => NULL,
        'type' => 'ul',
        'attributes' => array('class' => array('pager')),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at YOUR_SITE_ROOT/includes/pager.inc

I think you are looking for the **theme_pager_previous()** and **theme_pager_next()** functions.